# How do I remove a list object from an ObservedList in Python 3?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working on a discord bot and I use repl.it as a code editor.

I want to remove an ID from an "ObservedList" (don't really know what is the difference to a normal list).

This:

```
db['roles'] -= [id]
```

gives me the following error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'ObservedList' and 'list'
```

Comment: Instead of the the operator `-=` you should use the method designed for removing an item, without knowing `ObservedList` I would try `.remove(item)`.

Comment: Note this doesn't work with a normal list, either.

Comment: I could've sworn I already tried that lol... But it worked now, so thank you Klaus